# MSMQ security and performance

Tags: performance, security, msmq

I was wondering if anyone has done some performance testing with two different approaches for security. Mostly concerned with the server side of things.

1) Using active directory, the user account is validated each time a message is sent.

2) Using certificate, each message is encrypted with a certificate.

My guess would be that decrypting the message is more computer intensive hence the active directory approach is likely to perform better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Being a starter on MSMQ, I will do my best to answer the question here.

[1.] Securing a queue against access from accounts you don't want

Answer: My understanding is that if I use a private queue, it will implicitly do that. In other words, if anyone does not know about it, then how "outsiders" can access it ?

[2.] Ensuring a message is from the account it says it is (authentication)

Answer: I can debate about this. I am not sure it will make a difference in my particular environment since everything is driven by a custom app with structured data sent. If data is not structured the way it should be, the message will simply be ignored.

[3.] Ensuring no one can see the message body (encryption)

Answer: More relevant here, I do think that some level of encryption to prevent any "peeking" of the data.

Finally, I was not aware that the SID was inside the message header.

Let me know how performance is affected but these various security settings. Also, what's your advice on security with regards to MSMQ ?

Thx for all the info... 
Christian Martin

Comment: [1] So your idea of security is that if they don't know it's there how can they get to it? That's not security, that's crossing your fingers and hoping. To find the queue names, all I would have to do is sniff your network traffic and look at any MSMQ messages. Private queues are first choice unless you want to take advantage of extra functionality of public queues (like remote admin).

Comment: [3] You can encrypt in several ways. Examples: (a) sending messages over HTTPS with SSL; (b) sending messages over TCP with IPSEC enabled; (c) sending messages with body encryption enabled; (d) encrypting the custom data before putting in message. Which is easiest to implement and which is fastest depends on the infrastructure you have. I've never seen any comparitive stats but I would expect IPSEC to be fastest.

Comment: In general, I would recommend the following. (a) set queue level permissions to be as restrictive as possible whilst still allowing messages to flow; (b) enable authentication on the queue; (c) custom encrypt the data as messages are otherwise stored in queues unencrypted - MSMQ encryption is only on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mixed bits of security there.
Which ones do you require?

1. Securing a queue against access from accounts you don't want
2. Ensuring a message is from the account it says it is (authentication)
3. Ensuring no one can see the message body (encryption)

Let me know and I can give you a better idea of what works performancewise.

You write *"Using active directory, the user account is validated each time a message is sent."*
That doesn't sound right. All MSMQ does is put the SID of the sending user account in the message header. This is why you shouldn't rely on just setting account level access on queues as anyone can spoof the SID in an MSMQ message.

Cheers
John Breakwell